# Two groups of hierarchical selections in filter

Tags: hierarchy

Here is the case:

when [Hierarchy] value is **'A'**, a group of **[a]** selections displays in filter area.
When user switch [Hierarchy] to **‘B’**, all **[a]** selections are replaced by **[b]**  selections.
Solution **One** below might lead to an inconsistent display of selections

Solution **Two** puts these two groups of selections in toggle dropdown, and requires two more clicks when user wants to come back and make selection changes at any level.

Need a second person's opinion here. Which solution is better? Are there any other suggestions?
Great Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: See also http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/74920/13161

Comment: What does the user do after they have the appropriate dropdown set? Are they configuring once? Finding a set of objects (i.e. filtering)? It will help figure out the right way to build this interface...

Answer (score 1):

It seems really odd to have a hierarchy all on one line - it makes it look like the sub-items (a1, a2, b1, b2, etc) are on the same level as the category (A or B).

I would use a tree navigation, like this:

Closed state:

- A
- B

Opened out version:

- A

  - a1

    - a1a
    - a1b
    - a1c
    - a1d
  - a2

    - a2a
    - a2b
    - a2c
    - a2d
  - a3

    - a3a
    - a3b
    - a3c
    - a3d
- B

  - b1

    - b1a
    - b1b
    - b1c
    - b1d
  - b2

    - b2a
    - b2b
    - b2c
    - b2d
  - b3

    - b3a
    - b3b
    - b3c
    - b3d

items in the tree can have checkboxes or radio buttons next to them, whichever is appropriate

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Agree that 'It seems really odd to have a hierarchy all on one line ', but the context puts limit on UI pattern we are using.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is a menu with different stages :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0YB4m.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>